# Laravel Form: Specify that the value is an integer

Tags: php, forms, laravel, integer

Probably a really easy-to-solve problem but I can't find the answer.

The form is a dropdown that shows a specific text for the user (Less than 100... etc) but generates an integer after submission (99, 199 or 1999). Right the result of the submit is as a string.

```
    {{ Form::label('people','Nb of people')}}
    {{ Form::select('people', [
            '99' => 'Less than 100',
            '199' => 'Between 100 and 200',
            '1999' => 'More than 2000'])
    }}
```

EDIT (following itachi's comment):
The visitor needs to select one of these 3 options 'Less than 100' or 'Between 100 and 200' or 'More than 200'. Then the submission needs to send back an integer (easier to play with instead of a string) through GET method. The GET method part is working well but the issue is that the result is a STRING instead of an INTEGER.

Comment: you need to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So return the value as `intval`:

```
$value = intval(Input::only('people'));
// returns 99, 199 or 1999 instead of "99", "199" or "1999"
```

But since your example is a little vague, I really have no idea how/where you're handling this, so you'll have to adapt the above to fit your code.

Comment: It worked perfectly. 'intval' was the function I was looking for. Thank you Tim.